# creating unit test for sys.exit

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a simple python function.

```
def test():
    print "test"
    sys.exit(1)
```

I am using python 2.6. How can I create unittest for this function? This is because sys.exit can be handled in unit test cases after python 2.7.

can anyone let me know how to create unittest for this simple code?

Comment: What's the problem? In both 2.6 and 2.7 `sys.exit` is supposed to raise `SystemExit` exception. The unit test then only have to check that it raises the appropriate exception...

Comment: No it doesnt work in python 2.6. I have tested that.

Comment: Exactly which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.6

Answer (score 5):

According to what I can see there's been little change in `sys.exit` during the `2.x`. The only difference I can see is that earlier the `sys.exit` didn't check it's argument, but rather raised `SystemExit` exception anyway (now it only raises it if you supply a proper argument).

So for example I tried the following using python 2.6 (also known as 2.6.0):

```
import sys
try:
   sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit(1) as e:
   print repr(e)
```

and it responded with `SystemExit(1,)`

So your test should be something like:

```
def test():
    passed = False
    try:
        sys.exit(1)
    except SystemExit as e:
        if e.code == 1:
            passed = True

    assert passed
```

Comment: okay I will try. Is there any assertTrue, AssertFalse kind of thing for systemexit?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you asked for there. Could you elaborate?

Comment: can we do like this? self.assertFalse(test())

Comment: Not as my example was written as `test` doesn't return a value, but it can be modified to fit. The key point is that for the test to pass you need `sys.exit` to raise the exception with correct `code` - that is reach the `passed = True` statement.